# Отправка письма в отдельном потоке Java EE Servlet

Tags: java, многопоточность, servlet

Сделал отправку письма на E-Mail. Отправка сделана через Gmail, с авторизацией. Проблема в том что ответ от сервера клиенту приходит только тогда когда письмо отправлено, точнее функция отправки отработала.

Подскажите, как можно запустить этот процесс в отдельном потоке в `Serlvet-е`.

Спасибо.

**Решено:** Сам `JavaMail`, который я использую, уже поддерживает такое. При отправке письма нужно указать флаг `async`.

Comment: какой сервер вы используете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman tomcat8

Comment: это чистый сервлет или используете какой-то фреймворк?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman чистый. Решил. добавил в шапку.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.